# UPDATE MySQL and date time local field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

OK I have a insert statement works well a delete statement, is working.
However the UPDATE is not been on it for well over a day now and can not see the problem, only thing I think it could be is the date time local field in MySQL, but it works on insert.

**form**

```
$Band_id = (int)$_GET['id'];    
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bands where Band_id ='$Band_id'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="ammenddetails.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[Band_id]"?>">

    <tr><td>Band Name</td></br>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[Name]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><tr><td>Show Name</td></br>
    <td><input type="text" name="show" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[show]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><td>Venue</td></br>
    <td><input type="text" name="Venue" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[Venue]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><td>Category</td></br>
    <td><input type="text" name="Category" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[Category]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><td>Date and Time</td></br>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" name="time" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[time]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><td>Price</td></br>
    <td><input type="number" name="price" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[price]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><td>Stock</td></br>
    <td><input type="number" name="Stock" size="20" value="<? echo "$row[Stock]"?>"></td></tr></br>

    <tr><td>Infomation</td></br>
    <?php echo "<td><textarea name= 'infomation' cols=\"50\" rows=\"8\" >" .$row['infomation']. "</textarea></td>";?></tr></br>

    <tr><input type="submit"name="submit value" value="Update"></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
```

**ammenddetails.php**

```
 <?php
require 'core/init.php';
$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Name"]);
$show = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["show"]);
$Venue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Venue"]);
$Category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Category"]);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["price"]);
$Stock = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Stock"]);
$time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["time"]);
$infomation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["infomation"]);
$Band_id = (int)$_POST['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `bands`
              SET `Name`=`$Name`, 
                  `show`=`$show`,  
                  `Venue`=`$Venue`,
                  `Category`=`$Category`,
                  `price`=`$price`, 
                  `Stock`=`$Stock`, 
                  `time`=`$time`,
                  `infomation`=`$infomation`
              WHERE 
              `Band_id`=`$Band_id`");

echo "UPDATE `bands`
              SET `Name`=`$Name`, 
                  `show`=`$show`,  
                  `Venue`=`$Venue`,
                  `Category`=`$Category`,
                  `price`=`$price`, 
                  `Stock`=`$Stock`, 
                  `time`=`$time`,
                  `infomation`=`$infomation`
              WHERE 
              `Band_id`=`$Band_id`"
              // header("location:admin.php");
?>
```

the echo on the query shows up as:

```
UPDATE `bands` SET `Name`=`Coldplay`, `show`=`Time of you life`, `Venue`=`London Wembley `, `Category`=`Rock`, `price`=`2`, `Stock`=`20`, `time`=`2014-01-23T01:59`, `infomation`=`info here test` WHERE `Band_id`=`3`
```

have tried out suggestion query now outputs:

```
 UPDATE `bands` SET SET `Name`='Killers', `show`='Big Time High', `Venue`='London Apolo', `Category`='Rock', `price`='45', `Stock`='75', `time`='', `infomation`='BLOB values are trea' WHERE `Band_id`='1'
```

so the query is getting correct data just not updating the bd

Comment: Use backticks to escape table and column names. Use quotes to limit strings.

Comment: Thanks for the information I will try and implement that.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help. Although you've been careful to properly escape things here, you're one mistake away from disaster. Placeholder values provide an additional layer of safety.

Comment: Brilliant, I ordered a book on modern PDO phd the other day just awaiting Amazon to deliver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem.

```
SET `Name`=`$Name`,
```

You use ` to define fields, but for variables you need to use '

e.g.

```
SET `Name`='$Name',
```

....

a even better way is this:

```
SET `Name`='{$Name}',
```

....

try that and let me know! :)

Comment: Curly braces are not "better". They just fossilize dangerous SQL composition techniques using string interpolation.

Comment: @Vick I will try the second option and let you know if it works.

Comment: Curly braces are only required when the variable in question has something in it like `$_POST['value']` but those things should **never** be in your query in the first place. You're right in observing the wrong quotes were used. In MySQL either `'` or `"` is acceptable for values, `\`` only for database, table and column names.